# USCIS & US-DHS: E-Verify Company ID Number vs. E- Verify Client Company ID Number

Tags: usa, immigration, paperwork

This is related to United States immigration. I am filling a USCIS from. One of the questions in the form is as follows:

> E-Verify Company Identification Number, or a valid E-Verify Client Company Identification Number

My company has got both of these numbers. Though I am not sure which one should I be providing. Please note that I am the company's direct fulltime employee.

Please feel free to get back for clarifications or questions.